# Printing a dynamic HTML document

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, file, printing

I have an HTML template that we use for alerts. We pass some details into the template that pertain to the alert. What we are now trying to do is to get it to print. This HTML document is created dynamically so it isn't opened in a browser. I have been able to get the document to save to a network drive. I then copy it to the printer, but no luck printing. I have no idea if this is possible, but we need something that is well formatted, so plain text wouldn't be ideal. I have been searching for days, but can't seem to find anything that helps. Below is a sample of what i'm trying. The function below is called from a ASP.NET WEB API Endpoint, with the desired printer passed to it.

I'm open to all suggestions!

Thanks

```
Public Shared Function TestPrint(pPrinter As String) As String
    Dim tempateLoc As String = "\\JoshSv\Reject.htm"
    Dim printLoc As String = "\\printSv\" & pPrinter
    Dim fileLoc As String = "\\JoshSv\alert" & GetEpocTime(Now()) & ".htm"
    Dim fileHTML As String = ""

    If File.Exists(tempateLoc) Then
        Using tr As TextReader = New StreamReader(tempateLoc)
            fileHTML = tr.ReadToEnd
            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileLoc)
                sw.Write(fileHTML)
                File.Copy(fileLoc, printLoc)
            End Using
        End Using
    End If


    Return fileHTML
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the HTML document before you can print it.

See some [example code here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1da25ff0-0b6a-4779-9f73-ea13b8f92bc9/dynamically-print-html-content-from-vbnet-application?forum=vbgeneral).

Comment: this might work. I just edited the question a bit to clarify that i'm calling the function from an web api endpoint. I'm also, passing in a printer name on the network. But I think i might be able to work through it.

Comment: Are you using asp.net web api? I'm not sure this will work then. You might try [something like this](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/remote-printing-with-asp-net-web-api-in-windows-service/) instead.